# When does a javascript settimeout or setinterval function stop?

Tags: javascript

Will these functions always stop when user browses away from page, or closes the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will these functions always stop when user browses away from page, or closes the browser?

Yes, all javascript execution of the page stops, all timers and the browser memory allocated for it is cleared, both for the markup, style sheets and scripts. Whats left is only cookies, local storage and/or etags, but none of these run any code ever, if you have put such in the browser using javascript.

Comment: Are they also stopped when the page is re-loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're stopped in that case.

you can also manually stop them like this:

```
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
clearTimeout(t);
```